# Telerik controls are not loading properly after windows upgrade

Tags: telerik, http-status-code-404, .net-4.5, iis-10, windows-server-2022

Recently I have migrated a website which was running on Windows server 2012 R2, .Net Framework 4.5 and IIS 7 to Windows Server 2022, .Net Framework 4.8 and IIS 10. I did the migration by creating a new website in the new server and checked out the project folder using octopus and pointed it to the folder.

My website is using Telerik controls and we are using the version 2020.1.114.45. Sometimes when working with Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX, I get a 404 error that the requested URL was not found. Sometimes the site will load properly when I refresh the page, but most of the time the styles and controls will not load properly and even sometimes getting the site also not found (404) error . I saw some errors in chrome console [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7wJX.png).

I tried the following links to fix the problem, but nothing worked.

https://www.telerik.com/forums/controls-not-working-after-iis-deployment-telerik-is-undefined-error-throws-in-client-side-debuggin

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/knowledge-base/requested-url-not-found-error-404

I have also given the permissions to IIS user for the Telerik folder. I am using haproxy load balancer. There are also some virtual directories in the website and the paths are correctly pointed. I have integrated app pool and httphandlers and handlers are specified correctly.

Comment: The error "GET net::ERR_ABORTED 404 Not Found" occurs when one or more resources requested by the browser cannot be found on the server. To resolve this error, make sure:

1. The paths in the src attributes of your script tags are correct.
2. Your server is correctly configured to serve static files (JS, CSS, images, etc).
3. You haven't forgotten to specify the extension of the file you are loading.

Comment: @YurongDai Thanks for your reply. The files are located in the server and server is configured to serve the static files ( Verfied in Windows features and rolls).  There is another website in another windows 2012 server which uses the same code base is working without any issue.

Comment: You can enable the Telerik and Microsoft CDN to reduce the use of webresources and test again the app.

<telerik:RadScriptManager EnableCdn="true" 
    ID="RadScriptManager1"    
    runat="server"    
    CdnSettings-TelerikCdn="Enabled">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>

<telerik:RadStyleSheetManager runat="server" ID="RadStyleSheetManager1"
    CdnSettings-TelerikCdn="Enabled">
</telerik:RadStyleSheetManager>